# Math Domain Error with Standard Deviation

Tags: list, python-3.x

I'm having trouble calculating standard deviation in Python in a table (a list of lists).  I'm able to get 'population' standard deviation, but when I try to divide by n-1 for sample standard deviation, I get a math domain error. Here's my code:

```
# Row standard deviation
for i in range(ROWS):
    total = 0
    avg = 0
    sum2 = 0
    sum3 = 0
    stdDev = 0
    for j in range(COLUMNS):
        total = float(total + array[i][j])
        avg = total / len(array[0])
        sum2 = sum2 + (array[i][j])**2
        stdDev = sqrt((sum2 / (len(array[0])) - (avg*avg)))
    print(stdDev)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking the square root of a negative number, which `math` can't handle.

```
>>> math.sqrt(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```